# How can I convert a string in my JSON file into a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm working getting tweets from the Twitter API in my Rails backend. I'm able to create tweets in my db and then render the tweets as a JSON. But part of the tweet is still showing up as a string. How can I convert this specific part into a Ruby hash so that I can access the key:value pairs?

- I've tried .serializable_hash, .hash, to_json, but either the data type is wrong (needs to be an array) or it just adds more \ characters
- .strip, .split, .gsub also didn't work
- when I puts the string, it looks like a hash, but I'm not able to save that output

This is how the json is being rendered:

```
   "media": [
      "{\"id\"=>1159941035461529600, \"id_str\"=>\"1159941035461529600\", \"indices\"=>[62, 85], \"media_url\"=>\"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EBjwOeMVUAAVOia.jpg\", \"media_url_https\"=>\"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EBjwOeMVUAAVOia.jpg\", \"url\"=>\"https://t.asdco/mFwUSlGEpv\", \"display_url\"=>\"pic.twitter.com/mFwUSlGEpv\", \"expanded_url\"=>\"https://twitter.com/CommonBlackGirI/status/1159941046161170432/photo/1\", \"type\"=>\"photo\", \"sizes\"=>{\"thumb\"=>{\"w\"=>150, \"h\"=>150, \"resize\"=>\"crop\"}, \"medium\"=>{\"w\"=>1122, \"h\"=>819, \"resize\"=>\"fit\"}, \"large\"=>{\"w\"=>1122, \"h\"=>819, \"resize\"=>\"fit\"}, \"small\"=>{\"w\"=>680, \"h\"=>496, \"resize\"=>\"fit\"}}}"
    ]
```

I tried to create a method in the serializer file, but that didn't work because it's just string, not a traversable hash

```rb
  def media_url
    tweet = self.object
    tweet.media[0]
  end
```

I'd like to convert the string above into a Ruby hash so that I can get the media_url for each tweet

Comment: `JSON.parse` seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: That's a Ruby Hash being emitted raw instead of as a JSON object. Try `to_json` on it when rendering. `media_url` doesn't render, but something else does.

Comment: I tried JSON.parse, got this kind of error: 
JSON::ParserError (767: unexpected token at '{"screen_name"=>"KimberlyNFoster", "name"=>"Kimberly Nicole Foster", "id"=>142116606, "id_str"=>"142116606", "indices"=>[0, 16]}')

Comment: to_json added more "\"
 => "\"{\\\"screen_name\\\"=\\u003e\\\"KimberlyNFoster\\\", \\\"name\\\"=\\u003e\\\"Kimberly Nicole Foster\\\", \\\"id\\\"=\\u003e142116606, \\\"id_str\\\"=\\u003e\\\"142116606\\\", \\\"indices\\\"=\\u003e[0, 16]}\""

Comment: How did you end up with that? The object at `h[:"media"][0]` is not valid json ( it looks like a `Hash` converted to a `String` via `to_s`) If you need to convert a `Hash` to JSON the method is `to_json` but you should explain how this is being generated in the first place or just use the [`twitter`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem and not worry as much about the implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this would help:

```
def media_url
  tweet = self.object
  JSON.parse(tweet.media[0].gsub('=>', ':'))["media_url"]
end
```

You need to replace `=>` with `:` in order for `JSON.parse` to work

Or

To get the complete hash you can use a more generic method like `media`:

```
def media
  tweet = self.object
  JSON.parse(tweet.media[0].gsub('=>', ':'))
end
```